# Uploadify doesn't work in internet Explorer ("Select Files" button does nothing, ASP.NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, uploadify

I’m new here and I don’t speak English very well. Let’s see if you can understand me.
I’m using uploadify V 3.2.1 and it works great on Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 10 (haven’t tested it in other versions) When I click the Select Files nothing happens, I do have flash player installed and updated.

You can find the project here [Megaupload Link](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/461879/MultipleUploadDemo-rar.html) (Visual Studio 2008 C# Project)

Any Ideas??

The only difference between the debug info from IE and Chrome is that Chrome also adds this in the end

> SWF DEBUG: SWFUpload Init Complete
>   SWF DEBUG:
>   SWF DEBUG: ----- SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
>   SWF DEBUG: Build Number:           SWFUPLOAD 2.2.0
>   SWF DEBUG: movieName:              SWFUpload_0
>   SWF DEBUG: Upload URL:             /Upload.ashx
>   SWF DEBUG: File Types String:      *.*
>   SWF DEBUG: Parsed File Types:
>   SWF DEBUG: HTTP Success:           0
>   SWF DEBUG: File Types Description: All Files (*.*)
>   SWF DEBUG: File Size Limit:        0 bytes
>   SWF DEBUG: File Upload Limit:      0
>   SWF DEBUG: File Queue Limit:       999
>   SWF DEBUG: Post Params:
>   SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
>   SWF DEBUG:

And here's is the Head Code

```
<link href="CSS/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script src="Script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="Script/jquery.uploadify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id$='FileUpload1']").uploadify({
            'swf': 'Script/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': 'Upload.ashx',
            'debug':true
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

And this is the ASP Code

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

Internet Explorer Debug Info

> ---SWFUpload Instance Info---
>   Version: 2.2.0 2009-03-25
>   Movie Name: SWFUpload_0
>   Settings:
>       upload_url:               /Upload.ashx
>       flash_url:                Script/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1382033262511
>       use_query_string:         false
>       requeue_on_error:         false
>       http_success:
>       assume_success_timeout:   30
>       file_post_name:           Filedata
>       post_params:              [object Object]
>       file_types:               *.*
>       file_types_description:   All Files
>       file_size_limit:          0
>       file_upload_limit:        0
>       file_queue_limit:         999
>       debug:                    true
>       prevent_swf_caching:      true
>       button_placeholder_id:    FileUpload1
>       button_placeholder:       Not Set
>       button_image_url:         /
>       button_width:             120
>       button_height:            30
>       button_text:
>       button_text_style:        color: #000000; font-size: 16pt;
>       button_text_top_padding:  0
>       button_text_left_padding: 0
>       button_action:            -110
>       button_disabled:          false
>       custom_settings:          [object Object]
>   Event Handlers:
>       swfupload_loaded_handler assigned:  false
>       file_dialog_start_handler assigned: true
>       file_queued_handler assigned:       true
>       file_queue_error_handler assigned:  true
>       upload_start_handler assigned:      true
>       upload_progress_handler assigned:   true
>       upload_error_handler assigned:      true
>       upload_success_handler assigned:    true
>       upload_complete_handler assigned:   true
>       debug_handler assigned:             true

Chrome Debug Info

> ---SWFUpload Instance Info---
>   Version: 2.2.0 2009-03-25
>   Movie Name: SWFUpload_0
>   Settings:
>       upload_url:               /Upload.ashx
>       flash_url:                Script/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1382033429976
>       use_query_string:         false
>       requeue_on_error:         false
>       http_success:
>       assume_success_timeout:   30
>       file_post_name:           Filedata
>       post_params:              [object Object]
>       file_types:               *.*
>       file_types_description:   All Files
>       file_size_limit:          0
>       file_upload_limit:        0
>       file_queue_limit:         999
>       debug:                    true
>       prevent_swf_caching:      true
>       button_placeholder_id:    FileUpload1
>       button_placeholder:       Not Set
>       button_image_url:         /
>       button_width:             120
>       button_height:            30
>       button_text:
>       button_text_style:        color: #000000; font-size: 16pt;
>       button_text_top_padding:  0
>       button_text_left_padding: 0
>       button_action:            -110
>       button_disabled:          false
>       custom_settings:          [object Object]
>   Event Handlers:
>       swfupload_loaded_handler assigned:  false
>       file_dialog_start_handler assigned: true
>       file_queued_handler assigned:       true
>       file_queue_error_handler assigned:  true
>       upload_start_handler assigned:      true
>       upload_progress_handler assigned:   true
>       upload_error_handler assigned:      true
>       upload_success_handler assigned:    true
>       upload_complete_handler assigned:   true
>       debug_handler assigned:             true
>
> SWF DEBUG: SWFUpload Init Complete
>   SWF DEBUG:
>   SWF DEBUG: ----- SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
>   SWF DEBUG: Build Number:           SWFUPLOAD 2.2.0
>   SWF DEBUG: movieName:              SWFUpload_0
>   SWF DEBUG: Upload URL:             /Upload.ashx
>   SWF DEBUG: File Types String:      *.*
>   SWF DEBUG: Parsed File Types:
>   SWF DEBUG: HTTP Success:           0
>   SWF DEBUG: File Types Description: All Files (*.*)
>   SWF DEBUG: File Size Limit:        0 bytes
>   SWF DEBUG: File Upload Limit:      0
>   SWF DEBUG: File Queue Limit:       999
>   SWF DEBUG: Post Params:
>   SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
>   SWF DEBUG:

Comment: Please, narrow it down a little. Do you expect us to debug the whole project? (Or download some `*.rar` file from a sharehoster for that matter?) Can you show a extract relevant to your problem? See here: http://sscce.org/

Comment: The project only has an asp called Default, only the code for the button is there, there is another file that handles the upload process but i don't think that's the problem and also has the files used by uploadify, but I'll post the code in my question